# Magento - Control buttons when adding pictures to CMS showing in wrong language

Tags: magento, content-management-system

am having a problem that whenever I try to edit a page in CMS on Magento all the buttons eg add etc on the popups are showing in German. I can't find a way to swap them back to English.  Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default locale here;

```
System > config (TOP MENU)
```

Then;

```
> general (LEFT MENU)
```

And change; locale options > locale > English (UK)

You can also switch language on the fly in admin using the select box in the bottom left corner labelled 'Interface Locale'